# Windows 8 Programs' right-click menus/drop down lists showing up garbled

Tags: windows-8, user-interface

It seems more and more menus, drop down lists, etc. across many programs on my machine are showing garbage instead of their actual contents. Check out the screenshot:

[image: Messed up drop down list]

I don't recall if I had this issue in Windows 7, but it's possible (though it's only started going beyond drop down lists into even some tooltips. Here's a screenshot from a program I just downloaded (Quoll Writer):

[image: Quoll Writer messed up]

I'm running with a pair of not-bridged Radeon HD 4890 video cards (3 monitor setup), on Windows 8. It runs on an AMD Phenom II X4 945 processor, and 8GB of RAM. I don't seem to have any other graphical glitches (in video games, HD video, etc), but this one seems to be getting worse. Any ideas?

Chrome's bookmark bar's subfolder also suffers:

[image: Chrome Bookmark]

This in fact appears to be an issue with my ATI Radeon HD 4800 series drivers. Updating to the latest via Windows presents the same issue, but when I disable the third monitor (AK one of the two video cards), the glitches go away.

[AMD Support Thread created](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=449&threadid=172251)

Comment: Are you using Windows 8 certified, up-to-date drivers? Do you get the same issues in [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode)?

Comment: I let windows automatically update everything, and I don't think I've ever installed non-standard drivers manually. Checking in safe mode, everything renders correctly.

Comment: Try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) too, and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm logged in now after performing a clean boot. Screenshots 2 and 3 still occur, but the first one does not.

Comment: All right. Can you confirm that booting in safe mode again you don't get those glitches?

Comment: Confirmed: Booting in safe mode does indeed make those glitches go away. Definitely starting to look like a graphics thing? Safe mode only enables one of the two cards in a low resolution...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13462/discussion-between-and31415-and-scott)